# Moving files between Directories using Git

Tags: git

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.1, using Terminal for Git. I am taking a course on Git, so I am fairly new to all this.

I am trying to find out what process I need to do to move a .md file I have on my Desktop directory to other directory on my Mac. What commands should I use or what articles can I reference to learn how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: What does `git` have to do with it? Is one or both of the directories in question under version control?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need git to move files (unless it's specific to your class?), that's something that bash can do by itself with the `mv` command.

Ex: `mv myfile.md $HOME/Documents/example-directory/`

The above command would move `myfile.md` to the specified directory.